# Set entire row in datagridview to ReadOnly = false

Tags: c#

Same as the title, I need a ***default*** function to set the entire row in datagridview to ReadOnly = false.

Comment: Just one row? Not whole grid?

Comment: Is `DataGridView.ReadOnly = false;` not sufficient? If not, perhaps update your question with more detail, it's pretty vague as it stands. It's also worth reading [ask] and what a [mcve] is.

Comment: Sorry for the vague description. As I know, `DataGridView.ReadOnly = false;` is set the whole grid to read only while `DataGridView.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[CellIndex].ReadOnly = false;` is set a single cell, but what I need is to set one row to read only but not the whole grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridView.Rows[RowIndex].ReadOnly = false;
```